# Simple greedy algorithm. Infinite loop

Tags: c++, algorithm

I wrote a simple greedy algorithm, but somehow it doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float change;
    std::cout << "Change: ";
    std::cin >> change;
    int quantity = 0;
    while(change > 0.0){
        if(change >= 0.5){
            change -= 0.5;
        }
        else if(change >= 0.25){
            change -= 0.25;
        }
        else if(change >= 0.1){
            change -= 0.1;
        }
        else if(change >= 0.05){
            change -= 0.05;
        }
        else if(change >= 0.01){
            change -= 0.01;
        }
        quantity++;
        std::cout << change << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << quantity << std::endl;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

While it works for 0.5 and 0.25 it doesn't for 0.01 or 0.1 for example. (it looks like it returns some really small number)
I can't see where the problem is.

//EDIT
Converted everything to int values to avoid problem mentioned below [Zeno](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes#Dichotomy_paradox)

Comment: In C++ void as a list of parameters is not legal. Plus, main() must have the normal argc/argv and optionally envp.

Comment: What is the expected output if the user enters `0.001`?

Comment: Don't use floats for currency arithmetic. Start with that.

Comment: You might want to state what the algorithm is supposed to do.

Comment: I think you may have fallen victim to [Zeno](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes#Dichotomy_paradox).

Comment: What should I use for currency?

Comment: This might be an excellent time to introduce you to http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: @AlexisWilke `void` is legal in C++ as a parameter list, per C++11 § 8.3.5/4: "...The parameter list (void) is equivalent to the empty parameter list.". Further, `main` can have two allowable forms dictated by the standard. Per C++11 § 3.6.1, `int main()` and `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` are those forms, the former inferred if `(void)` is specified per C++11 § 8.3.5/4. An implementation may *add* parameters, but should do so with the second form *past* argv (as your `envp` example does).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is elementary: While 0.5, 0.25, 0.125, ... are 'exact' floating point numbers 0.1, 0.01 are not: You compare/subtract is wrong.
In the set 0.1 ... 0.9 the only 'exact' floating point is 0.5.

(All of that assumes binary floating points)

Comment: obligatory link: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need a case when change is between 0.01 and 0.0, maybe avoid the last if()?

```
    else if(change >= 0.05){
        change -= 0.05;
    }
    else /*if(change >= 0.01)*/ {
        change -= 0.01;
    }
```